# How to reset MATLAB layout to default (commandline)

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

How do I reset the layout of Matlab in commandline instead of clicking it (shown below)? Googled but could not find, this question/answer might help others to find this information.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [undocumentedmatlab.com](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/setting-the-matlab-desktop-layout-programmatically):

```
desktop = com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance;
desktop.restoreLayout('Default');
```

Comment: This worked out of the box / as expected with Matlab 2020B, thank you